Alignment Issues with Numbering and Bullets Using \useinnertheme{rectangles} in Beamer
I'm working on a Beamer presentation and I recently switched to using the \useinnertheme{rectangles} option to achieve a more square-like appearance for all list elements. However, I'm encountering alignment issues where the two digit numbers are not centered properly.
Here is my code:
\documentclass[italian,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item One
    \item Two
    \item Three
    \item Four
    \item Five
    \item Six
    \item Seven
    \item Eight
    \item Nine
    \item Ten
    \item Eleven
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}




You could redefine the enumerate item template to make it a tiny bit wider. This way there will be enough room for two digits:
\documentclass[italian,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{
  \hbox{%
    \usebeamerfont*{item projected}%
    \usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
    \vrule width2.5ex height1.85ex depth.4ex%
    \hskip-2.5ex%
    \hbox to2.5ex{%
      \hfil%
      \color{fg}\insertenumlabel%
      \hfil}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item One
    \item Two
    \item Three
    \item Four
    \item Five
    \item Six
    \item Seven
    \item Eight
    \item Nine
    \item Ten
    \item Eleven
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



thanks for the answer but it doesnt work with other list of items such as TOC. I added another example into the question

@Sadegh You will have to redefine all lists. Please don't edit questions in a way which invalidate existing answers. Ask a new question if you can't translate this to other occurrences of squares.
